# google sheets script wont get value for subject

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make an auto emailer with the google sheets script tool and I took this code directly from google and did some very minor adjustments so it will add subject and so i can better understand it...or so i thought, it sends emails fine but evert test email i get does not have a subject.

```js
sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // Starts at row 2, row 1 has all the titles
  var numRows = 2; // Allows the HORIZONTAL rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2); // Set range to process
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); //Assign values to the range
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column (email address)
    var message = row[1]; // Second column (message)
    var subject = row[2]; // Third column (subject)
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

furthermore if there is any other way for me to do this cleaner then I am open for more advice and tips. thank you.

Comment: In your script, `sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)` is used as the range for retrieving the values. In this case, the columns "A" and "B" are retrieved. I think that this is the reason of your issue. Although I'm not sure about your Spreadsheet, if `subject` is put in the column "C", please modify to `sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) By this, `var subject = row[2]` has the value of the column "C".

Answer (score 0):

### Issue with your code:

In your script, sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) is used as the range for retrieving the values. In this case, the columns "A" and "B" are retrieved.

### Solution

The subject is put in the column "C", please modify to sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3). By this, var subject = row[2] has the value of the column "C".

### Reference

[getRange(row,column,numrows,numcolumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

– Tanaike